# Bold or Italic, not both! on wysihtml5

Tags: javascript, wysihtml5

I am using wysihtml5 (https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5) with the toolbar provided.

What I need is when you mark a text to become bold, it removes all the others tags, especially the italic one.

Comment: try to use <strong> for bold and <em> for italic.

Comment: but this is not the problem... what I must avoid is this: <b><i>Hi!</i></b> `b` inside `i` or viceversa